# GeoJSON draw in 3d.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with the library cartogram.js (here you can see an example of how it works)

http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/#netmigrate/2011

I'm trying to do the same, and do it with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>cartogram</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/cartogram.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="map"></svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cartogram = d3.cartogram()
  .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa())
  .value(function(d) {
    return Math.random() * 100;
  });
 d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawnbot/d3-cartogram/master/data/us-states.topojson", function(topology) {
  var features = cartogram(topology, topology.objects.states.geometries);
     console.log(features);
  d3.select("svg").selectAll("path")
    .data(features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("d", cartogram.path);
 });
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that nothing appears to me, nor I get no errors. and I'm sure the GeoJSON file is called and processed. What should I do to display the map? I am new to d3.js. what is the problem? my json is the same of the link.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK friend I tried, but I do not know how to import libraries. The code is ready to make a copy and paste in an apache server run it. I hope you help me please!

Answer (score 0):

`selection.data()` only accepts an array as data.
In your example, `features` is not an array, it's a complex object containing a property `features` and a property `arcs`.

The map is displayed when you use `features.features` (as well as extending dimensions of svg) :

```
d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(features.features)
    .enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", cartogram.path);
```

Comment: really this works! thank you!. I wanted to ask another question using its extensive knowledge. My next challenge is to show on the map only coordinates of Colombia, for example, a region of Colombia with the coordinates: 5.5793665, -75.4555669.

Comment: would you change? or should I do?